# facebook app namespace and the facebook page name

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

i have a question about facebook page and facebook app.

Let's assume that, i have a company. and my company name is grimFandango. Before i put this company name i have checked facebook page:facebook.com/grimFandango.

it was available. But i did not take it. (this was a mistake) And then i have developed an ios/android application for my company. i used "login with facebook" feature on my mobile applications. That means i have also created a "Facebook App" on developers.facebook.com web site. I put same name (grimFandango) as a namespace for facebook app on developers.facebook.com

when we are done with mobile applications and facebook app. i wanted to get facebook.com page (facebook.com/grimFandago). But it looks like i cant take this page with that grimFandago.

what do you think? I cant get this facebook page name because someone took that that page name (facebook.com/grimFandango) OR because of the facebook app namespace?

thanks,
selcuk

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, because someone took it (it can be unpublished too, btw). There is no direct relation between page names and app namespaces. They are even on different subdomains (apps.facebook.com).

Comment: thanks. Is this your comment or exact information? by the way when i write facebook.com/grimFandango (this is not real) I cant see any page. And if you are explain this problem with because they are on different subdomains.. I think it does not make sense.

Comment: pages can also be unpublished. either way, it´s my personal and experienced comment, which is 99% correct. if you want to be 100% sure, you will have to contact facebook directly - or just do a simple test. i can only tell you that there is no relation between page name and app namespace.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, i dont want to change namespace of the facebook App. cuz i dont want it to effect my application "login with facebook" feature. let me ask facebook directly.